# Windows 10 disk encryption

Tags: windows-10, disk-encryption

I have a Windows 10 Home, which as I understood from online tutorials does not support windows built in encryption tools like Bitlocker.

Moreover, it seems that may device does not support encryption anyway, as under System Information/Device encryption support I do not have "meets prerequisites", as mentioned [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-device-encryption-windows-10-home), but rather (translated): "Possible causes of automatic device encryption failure..."

Nevertheless, I would really like to encrypt the drive, in case the computer is stolen, on the other hand would be really nice if it is done in the background or close to that, so it does not disrupt the current workflow (meaning I dont need to choose some file, move it in a specific folder, encrypt and add new files by hand). Basically a full drive encryption. What are my options?

I was reading about TrueCrypt, but there is a [warning](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) on their website:

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to upgrade to windows 10 Pro and use bitlocker. Despite what you might think, you don't have to pay the $200 for the pro license. If you buy (or have) an old windows 7 pro/ultimate license, you can use that product key to get windows 10 pro. All you have to do is go to settings (`win` + `i`) then Update and Securty. Click on activation in the sidebar, and hit change product key. Then type in your product key and you have windows 10 pro. Because of windows 7 hitting EOS the keys are really cheap on ebay.